# paper-input polymer element in dart won't show error message

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer, paper-elements

I'm trying to get an error validation message to show at all. This code:

```
<paper-input error="test" autoValidate required></paper-input>
```

Just shows a blank input field. What am I missing here?

I've also tried this code from the demo page at https://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-elements/demo.html#paper-input:

```
<paper-input-decorator label="required" floatingLabel error="input is required!" autoValidate>
  <input is="core-input" required>
</paper-input-decorator>
```

And it also does not produce a validation error message, just a normal text input field with no decorations other than the label.

I'm using Dart 1.8.5, polymer 0.15.5+3, and paper_elements 0.6.1.

Comment: Why should it show an error message? You didn't restrict what is allowed in any way.

Comment: The restriction is the word "required". I'm basing this on the demo at https://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-elements/demo.html#paper-input Granted it's a little tweaked from the example there, but the original example doesn't work either.

Comment: Sorry, i missed that, was about to leave. I guess this is not supported with paper-input. Use paper-input-decorator instead.

Comment: As I said, I tried the example in the demo page (which uses paper-input-decorator), and it does not work either. I'll update the question with this info.